# SSAS best way to count Orders by number of Products ordered

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm looking for the best way to implement measure that counts Orders by the number of products ordered.

There is a fact table of ProductsOrdered, like this

```
CREATE TABLE ProductsOrdered (
    IdOrder UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    IdProduct UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    OrderDate DATE,
    Quantity INT,
    Price DECIMAL(18,2)
)
```

for every order there are rows in the table for every kind of product ordered.

I would like to have a measure that counts how many ordered a single product, how many 2, and so on.

Just like this SQL query does.

```
SELECT OrderedProductNumber, COUNT(IdOrder) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM (
    SELECT IdOrder, COUNT(IdProduct) AS OrderedProductNumber
    FROM ProductsOrdered
    GROUP BY IdOrder
) t
GROUP BY OrderedProductNumber
```

Which MDX expression is best counterpart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you can only produce a count by a dimension. In this case, your dimension is the products ordered (1, 2, 3, etc.) Your option is to create a physical dimension that has the range of possibilities (tedious), or to create "dummy" members for a dimension to do the same thing as a calculation (tedious AND likely a performance problem). I would lean towards creating a dimension for products ordered, and then create a fact table using your SQL query and add the dimension and measure group to the cube. It's going to be easier to implement in the long run and by physically instantiating the counts, you will get much better query performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define dimension based on product
then measure group based on fact  table, that you named ProductOrdered,
 then you can define distinct count measure based on your IOrder column (e.g `[IOrderdistinctcount]`)

after that you can use

```
select 
{IOrderdstinccount} on 0,
[dim Product].[product].[Product].members on 1
from [Cube]
```